# Laravel+vuejs, how to loop inside table td tag?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Below shows my data. I am trying to loop `Item` inside table `<td>` tag so that it forms two items in one column.

```
user
    >"name":"Bob"
    >"id":1
    >"Item":
        >"name":"Desk"
        >"name":"Chair"
```

**Code**

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Items</th>
        </tr>

        <tr v-for="use in user.data" :key="use.id">
            <td>{{ use.name }}</td>
            <td v-for="a in use.item">
                {{ a.name }},
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

But when I do the codes above, it produce another column just like below picture. How do I put the `Desk` and `Chair` sits together in one column?

[image]

Comment: which css framework you are using?

Comment: I'm using adminlte

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi just use a span tag in side td here is my solution, p or div tag are block tags, if you are using bootstrap 4 just set class to span inline-block or inline

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Items</th>
        </tr>

        <tr v-for="use in user.data" :key="use.id">
            <td>{{ use.name }}</td>
            <td>
                <span v-for="a in use.item"> {{ a.name }}, </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: how do i remove the last `,` (since it display `Desk, Chair,`)? is there a function in vue to remove the last character?

Comment: can i see your controller code how you are getting items there will be better solution from php side no need to loop on front-end.

Answer (score 0):

`v-for` crates another elemenrs for you in each iteration. Use `join` function to display together

```
    <tr v-for="use in user.data" :key="use.id">
        <td>{{ use.name }}</td>
        <td>
            {{ use.item.join(", ") }},
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Output would be `Desk, Chair`

Comment: under item column, i got `[object Object], [object Object]`

Comment: make `use.item` as array

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with using [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11)
`

```
  <tr v-for="use in user.data" :key="use.id">
      <td>{{ use.name }}</td>
      <td>
         {{ _.map(use.item, 'name').join(", ") }}
      </td>
  </tr>
```

`

Comment: I have an error `Property or method "_" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render`

Comment: [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11) iam used this for pluck name from object need to include your file